# How to refresh table after complicted ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mobile

I have a table that loads data on loading of the page. There are 3 buttons that will reload the table based on the data available per user. THe problem is my reflow table stops rendering and reverts to plain HTML which cannot happen since there are a lot of table cells that are getting cut off.

This is the javascript call which start it

```
javascript:LoadGames('0','open')
```

This leads to a function in a different file (there are several files).

```
function LoadGames(type,status){
var action = 'loadgames';   
var foldersOut = fixAjaxURL();
document.getElementById("live").className = "";
document.getElementById("open").className = "";
document.getElementById("completed").className = "";
document.getElementById(status).className = "selected";

ObjAjax.setMethod('GET');       
ObjAjax.setURL(foldersOut +'phpajax/loadMyContest.ajax.php');
ObjAjax.setParameter('action',action);
ObjAjax.setParameter('type',type);
ObjAjax.setComplete( GameControlResponse );
ObjAjax.execute(); }
```

which leads to this response function

```
function GameControlResponse(){
var ResponseContainer = document.getElementById('TableContainer');
if(ResponseContainer!=null)
{
    if((ObjAjax.getResponseText()==1)||(ObjAjax.getResponseText()=='1'))
    {
        document.location.reload(true);
    }
    else{
        ResponseContainer.innerHTML = ObjAjax.getResponseText();
        var InlineScriptsonCallback = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        if(InlineScriptsonCallback != null)
        {
            for(var z=0; z < InlineScriptsonCallback.length;z++)
            {
        if(InlineScriptsonCallback[z].className=="evaluableoncallback")
                {
                    eval(InlineScriptsonCallback[z].innerHTML);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    alert('AjaxerError: Container doesnt exist');
}}
```

so after that reloads I am left with a plain table rendering with out the jquery mobile styling.

I've tried `$("#my-game-table").table('refresh');`

but I may be putting in the wrong spot or maybe there is something easier I am missing. I am a little rusty on php ajax manipulation so any help would go a long way.